# How to solve this ode of the distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I want to solve the following ode of distribution,
$$\partial_y^2 f(x,y)=\delta_x,$$
where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac delta function defined by $\left<\delta_x,g(y)\right>=g(x).$

I did some attempts,
$$\left<\partial_y^2 f(x,y),\phi(y)\right>=\left<f(x,y),\partial_y^2\phi(y)\right>=\phi(x).$$

But I can't get the explicit formula of $f(x,y).$

Comment: Is $f$ a distribution on $\mathbb R^2$ ? If so, why do the test functions $g$ and $\phi$ depend only on $y$ ? If not, why does $f$ depend on $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: No, you can treat x as a parameter.

Comment: f is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hints : A distribution with vanishing derivative is a constant function. An anti-derivative of the delta distribution is the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the the well known and easy to proof formulas:
$$
\partial_yH(y-x)=\delta_x\\
\partial_y(|y-x|)=sgn(y-x)
$$
where the equality is to be understood in a distributional sense. With these formulas you can straightforward integrate the ODE w.r.t. $y$ twice.

Alternatively, you can (in a first step) restrict yourself to test functions  whose (compact) support lies entirely above or below $x$. The ODE for such test functions obviously reads
$$
\partial_y^2f(x,y)=0
$$
Thus, we get a potential full solution by
$$
f=\begin{cases}
yg_-(x)+h_-(x)&y<x\\
yg_+(x)+h_+(x)&y<x
\end{cases}
$$
Now you simply need to fit $g_\pm, h_\pm$ such that $f$ is continous and its second distributional derivate yields the $\delta_x$.

Either way you end up with something like this
$$
f=\frac{1}{2}|y-x| + y g(x) + h(x)
$$